# Autodesk FORGE: Get Geometries

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

Good morning. I am trying to extract geometries with the autodesk forge tutorial and I have a problem.
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/xtract-geometry-from-source-file/task5-extract_geometry/
First I do the extraction for some specific object ids and it works correctly, I download the file and read its geometries. The problem is that if I change the object ids from step 1, in step 2 of verifying the job, it keeps returning the references from the first time I used the job. It's as if it doesn't refresh the new object ids. What could be happening?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In response of step 1 with new ObjectID's, you will get the new URN "URL_SAFE_URN_OF_SOURCE_FILE>"..
Use this URN in Step 2 to check status of Job
'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/<URL_SAFE_URN_OF_SOURCE_FILE>/manifest'